# Nested If statement to cut & paste rows to different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Could someone help with this code?

I'm comparing two workbooks. I've built a For loop to check to see if the unique ids in workbook1 match the ids in workbook2.
If they match I'm assigning the returned row # to variable lrow. I then need to check the value in column C for the returned row. 
Depending on the value in lrow, column C I need to cut the row in workbook1, sheet1 and paste to different sheets in workbook1. I also 
need to delete the row that was cut so I dont have blank rows when done.

I'm getting a syntax error on the nested Else If statements. They are all highlighted in red. I'm also getting a Compile error on 
these lines that says "Must be first statement on the line".

Could you let me know what I'm missing with the nested if and also verify if my cut and paste operation is valid.

Thanks for your assistance.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Complete()

Dim Lastrow, Newrow As Long
Dim i, lrow As Long
Dim wb1, wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1, ws2 As Worksheet

' Turn off notifications

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\workbook2.xlsx"
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1")  

With wb1.Worksheets(ws1)

  Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To Lastrow

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "G").Value, ws2.Columns("A"), 0)) Then

      lrow = Application.Match(.Cells(i, "G").Value, ws2.Columns("A"), 0)

        If ws2.Cells(lrow,"C") = 18 Then

          Newrow = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Cut wb1.Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(newrow,"A")
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Delete

        ElseIf ws2.Cells(lrow,"C") = 23 Then

          Newrow = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Cut wb1.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(newrow,"A")
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Delete

        ElseIf ws2.Cells(lrow,"C") = 24 Then

          Newrow = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Cut wb1.Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(newrow,"A")
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Delete

        ElseIf ws2.Cells(lrow,"C") = 36 Then

          Newrow = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet5").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Cut wb1.Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(newrow,"A")
          ws1.Cells(i,"G").EntireRow.Delete

        End If
  End If
    Next i
End With

Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx").Close savechanges:=False

' Turn on notifications
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Message Box showing that process is complete.

    MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Change all "Else If" to "ElseIf"

Comment: @paulbica, I've made the changes you suggested. But now I'm getting a Type Mismatch error on this line:    If Application.Match(.Cells(i, "G").Value, ws2.Columns("A"), 0) Then

Answer (score 0):

From the last comment I made to @paulbica I corrected the line to read:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, "G").Value, ws2.Columns("A"), 0)) Then
```

The code now runs correctly. I've update the post to reflect the changes made.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's good that you solved the Type mismatch error, but there are a couple of issues left

The line `With wb1.Worksheets(ws1)` will throw another Type mismatch error because the Worksheets function takes the sheet name or index as an argument and ws1 is a Worksheet object, so it should be changed to `With wb1.Worksheets(ws1.Name)` or simply `With ws1`

The loop implemented like that will skip rows if they are contiguous. For example, if you start with a total of 5 rows, all of which need to be moved, in the first iteration i is 2 and row 2 will be deleted. Next iteration row 3 had become row 2 after deletion, but i is now 3, so the initial row 3 is skipped and processing moves to current row 3 which previously was 4

Depending on how much data you have your code is quite slow because it interacts with the ranges very often. For example it's extracting the value of `ws2.Cells(lrow,"C")` for every If branch, extracting the last row in sheets 3, 4, and 5 for every cut operation, and deleting rows one at the time

This is how I'd write the code:

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Complete()
    Dim i As Long, toDel As Range, copyCell As Range
    Dim ws11 As Worksheet, ws13 As Worksheet, ws14 As Worksheet, ws15 As Worksheet
    Dim ws13LR As Long, ws14LR As Long, ws15LR As Long
    Dim wb2 As Workbook, ws21 As Worksheet, wb2row As Variant, wb2colA As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\workbook2.xlsx"
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xlsx")
    Set ws11 = Sheet1

    Set ws13 = Sheet3:          ws13LR = ws13.Cells(ws13.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set ws14 = Sheet4:          ws14LR = ws14.Cells(ws14.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set ws15 = Sheet5:          ws15LR = ws15.Cells(ws15.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set ws21 = wb2.Sheets(1):   wb2colA = ws21.UsedRange.Columns("A").Value2

    For i = 2 To ws11.Cells(ws11.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wb2row = Application.Match(ws11.UsedRange.Cells(i, "G").Value, wb2colA, 0)
        If Not IsError(wb2row) Then
            Set copyCell = Nothing
            Select Case ws21.Cells(wb2row, "C").Value2
                Case 18:      Set copyCell = ws13.Cells(ws13LR, "A"): ws13LR = ws13LR + 1
                Case 23, 24:  Set copyCell = ws14.Cells(ws14LR, "A"): ws14LR = ws14LR + 1
                Case 36:      Set copyCell = ws15.Cells(ws15LR, "A"): ws15LR = ws15LR + 1
            End Select
            If Not copyCell Is Nothing Then
                With ws11.UsedRange
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy copyCell
                    If toDel Is Nothing Then
                        Set toDel = .Rows(i)
                    Else
                        Set toDel = Union(toDel, .Rows(i))
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    wb2.Close False
    toDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

---

I moved all unnecessary operations out of the For loop, and created a new range of rows to be deleted at the end, in one operation